# Mixing up the order of Retzei and Ya'aleh V'yavoh?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, mistakes, bentching, rosh-chodesh-new-month

If someone is *bentching* on Shabbat-Rosh Chodesh, and accidentally skips Retzei, but says Ya'aleh V'yavoh, can they then say Retzei after Ya'aleh V'yavoh, but before Uvenei? Or must they continue and say the "make up" bracha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Mishna B'rura* 188](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%97):13 and [*Aruch Hashulchan* 188:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%97#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A7.D7.A4.D7.97_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96) say you say "*R'tze*" and continue with "*Uvne*" thereafter.